# gcm maven dependency error

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, google-cloud-messaging

I converted my dynamic web project to maven project. gcm was working fine with dynamic project but in maven dependency It is not working

Showing some error in pom.xml page "Missing artifact com.google.android.gcm:gcm-server:jar:1.0.2" when I added gcm-server maven dependency. Someone please suggest some solution I am new to this maven projects.

Comment: check your local repository constins the gcm jars files or not?

Comment: Got buddy. It was wrong usage of GroupId. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a wrong groupId. You need to use this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: work like a charm. Thanks a lot buddy. groupId was wrong.

Comment: No problem, but it might help others to accept this answer as the correct one if it works!